# My version of Notepad++ does not create backups

Tags: backup, notepad++

What I am trying to do is recover a file that was accidentally "not saved" or "not saved properly".  Anyway, I was working with a document and up popped a window asking me to do something with the file.  The problem was that I was in a hurry and the window that popped up gave me a "yes" or "no" answer and nothing would make the window go away, so - you guessed it - I hit the "wrong" button.  Did all kinds of research and found that my installed Notepad++ decided that it would have nothing to do with anything so crude as making a backup of the file - anywhere.

Oh, my version is setup to make a backup "every 7 seconds"; which my computer shows to be blatantly wrong.

Anyone have any idea(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Check %APPDATA%\Notepad++\backup and the its install dir's backup subdir.

But if you answered no to saving it, it's probably lost.

You can test the 7-second backup by editing a file, then killing Notepad++ with task manager (after 7) and looking for that saved file in those backup dirs. Then restart Notepad++ and see if it remembers your edits.